# Consequences if using PHP include TEMPLATEPATH?

Tags: theme-development, theme-options, settings-api

I have created a **Theme Options page** using Settings API so now I need to style it using CSS.
Instead using function like this inside **functions.php**

```
function mytheme_add_init() {
if ( is_admin() ) {
    $get_path=get_bloginfo('template_directory');
    wp_enqueue_style("functions", $get_path."/css/admin.css", false, "1.0", "all");

    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_add_init' );
```

I am using `<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/functions/admin_css.php"); ?>` directly inside my file responsible for creating my **Theme Options Page**. Reason for this approach is that I will use some images *(their path will be dynamicly generated using `get_template_directory_uri()` thingy)* inside my **Options Page**.

So what really want is to add my theme to **WordPress.org repository**.

**Question:** Because I am using that approach will I ***suffer consequences*** like being my theme rejected by **WordPress Theme Review Team ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that will get rejected. It's also wholly unnecessary, since you can use relative paths to the images in your CSS file, you don't need to have them dynamically generated.

Comment: Note: you'll also get rejected for using `TEMPLATEPATH` or `get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' )`, instead of **`get_template_directory_uri()`**.